# How to correctly set this wired Internet connection on Debian?

Tags: debian, home-networking

I need to create new network settings for my Debian Jessie installation because it doesn't seem to work anymore after the router got broken and I plugged in the main network cable directly. The initial settings were created automatically during the OS installation.

The ISP only offers tech support for Windows and Mac OS.

I've managed to obtain a working connection on the Windows 7 OS running in Virtual Box, I just provided a user and a password while creating a new broadband connection. I can't do that on Debian because I don't know what's wrong, I don't have networking skills and trying various advice given for other situations didn't help, and maybe did more harm than good. Like, for instance, when trying to create a new VPN/DSL connection from the GUI, I'm only given the choice of providing a file for the settings, and I don't have such a file. So I've tried bypassing that using `nm-connection-editor`, but I got tons of warnings in the terminal and the connection created that way was turning off the second I tried to turn it on. Also, many tutorials start with using `pppoeconf`, but I get `bash: pppoeconf: command not found` with it. To use apt-get I need the connection first, and if it could connect before without `pppoeconf`, what makes it unable to connect now?

This is what I get with ipconfig in Windows:

```
Windows IP Configuration


PPP adapter Broadband Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2f0d:1af:ffff::4f74:406b
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4f74:406b%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 79.116.64.107
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%18
                                       0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a975:71b:e3f0:ad2b%11
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.173.43
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0CAC39B9-EEC5-4D41-8D27-E9460A997045}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{628C2C2B-2578-435A-9C9A-EEC36786D9A1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

And here is what I get with ifconfig in Debian:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:5a:0d:2d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:64ff:fe5a:d2d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:60232104 (57.4 MiB)  TX bytes:6649205 (6.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:18 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:5a:0d:2d  
          inet addr:169.254.4.17  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:783594 (765.2 KiB)  TX bytes:783594 (765.2 KiB)
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Most liely, the connection to your provider must be established using `PPPoE`, which is not the same as `TCP/IP` which Debian offers you without the PPPoE packages.